# my username and password is missing when submit it using vba for internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, html

My username and password is missing during submission in this website: https://play.playup.com/ 
this link address is stored in the one of the cell name E4, can anyone please help me to solve this problem? Please check this code in your editor for better understanding...
username: ajmsanvesh143@gmail.com
password: ajms6237
code:

```
Sub clicksignupurl()
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.Visible = True
url_name = Sheet1.Range("E4")
If url_name = "" Then Exit Sub
ie.navigate url_name
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4
Set allhyperlinks = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    For Each hyper_link In allhyperlinks
        If hyper_link.innertext = "Sign In" Then
            hyper_link.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Set mailid = ie.document.getelementbyid("username")
mailid.Value = "xxxxxxxxx"
Set passid = ie.document.getelementbyid("password")
passid.Value = "xxxxxxx"
Set allhyper = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each hyper_link In allhyper
        If hyper_link.innertext = "Sign in" Then
            hyper_link.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd warmly recommend you go and change your password RIGHT NOW before it's too late. I've flagged your post for a moderator to hopefully redact revision 1 away. Please be careful in the future, and in any case VBA code shouldn't contain any hard-coded credentials whatsoever.

Comment: i changed already ,now the username and password are entered in specific places .they are missed whenever the sign in button enter through code.i thought the web page has more security .how can i avoid that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting for the new page to load after the first hyperlink click. Add this line after the Next.

```
...
Next

do while ie.busy or ie.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: loop  'need this!

Set mailid = ie.document.getelementbyid("username")
...
```

Comment: thats not a problem the is no need to load any page.when i pressed sign in button , a sign in wizard is opened to enter user name and password.but my problem is "after enterintg username and password ,i show my id and password in respective coloumn but they are remove when i pressed the submit button.